# EACCES Denied (Permission Denied) While accessing pictures from external SD card

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gallery

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20160312_173247.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

How to Overcome this Problem: It happens only when accessing the picture from External SD Card. I already provide the Permission like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

The code i need is uploading image from the gallery(picture either from InternalStorage or External Storage) without any error or exception

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException` are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: File not exist /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20160312_173247.jpg

Comment: you have to add dynamic permission to the app.. from your activity.

Comment: how to provide dynamic permission in android 6.0 and in lower versions

Comment: Check the code from http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11894613 (it happens when uploading a camera image from gallery)